# Interval visualization

Tags: intervals

I was experimenting with visualizing intervals to assist in learning them, drawing on experience with a 12 hour clock face I decided on:
[image]
Do you think such a visualization is helpful for learning intervals?

Later I found people already developed the same idea here:

- http://harmonagon.com/#
- https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFKcevgRavAcrEcYSYv7Y-BEY5pyOH_Rf

Comment: This a matter of opinion not fact.

Comment: Personally, i'd consider that a horrible mnemonic. I can visualise them on a keyboard, but throw that type of diagram at me & suddenly I have 15 things to learn, not one.

Comment: Who decided to spell "3rd" as "3th"?

Comment: _Who decided to spell "3rd" as "3th"?_  Vic Firth probably.

Comment: For me, connecting intervals with sounds instead of images is more musically edifying.

Comment: Ah, this made me want to make fingerboard charts with varied row/column step sizes, could help me find more patterns for stepping around.

Comment: It would certainly be more useful to visualize intervals on a piano keyboard, rather than a clock face.

Comment: @BrianTowers It's not matter of an opinion. Efficiency of a teaching method is definitely something that can be objectively studied.

Comment: The main stumbling block is enharmonics. Someone using Bb as one of the notes will be totally confused - and wrongly informed when using A# instead.

Answer (score 2):

1. The diagrams don't include enharmonic equivalents. E.g. C-D# is not a minor third. It is an augmented second. This is an entry level material, so the students may not recognize that, and learn the wrong thing.
2. Musicians already learn several ways of visualising notes: the music notation, and location of notes on instruments, piano or other. Arranging notes in a circle would be yet another thing to learn. It's not completely unused, in particular a circle of fifth is commonly used, but it's not a standard music notation.
3. The diagrams demonstrate nicely how various intervals complement (or not) to octave. They can help to understand that topic. It could also work with simple chords. But for 9, 11 and 13 chords it would possibly complicate more than simplify.

Comment: 1 Thanks for your feedback, as you can probably tell I'm not a music theory expert.2 Another thing to learn, yes, but not something to recall on the spot, just another perspective. Maybe you like better this system I found later by people that do know their theory: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFKcevgRavAcrEcYSYv7Y-BEY5pyOH_Rf

Answer (score 1):

Hm, it depends on what you actually want to learn about intervals. This is effectively a representation of the orbits of the canonical group action Z, Z_12 -> Z_12, aswell as the cosets of the resulting subgroups. This can be a nice visualisation for how these intervals stack up, but they will certainly not teach a lot of the more common teachnings of intervals. So yes, your illustrations are useful if this is the thing you want to explain. This could for example be quite useful to see how different intervals allow us to go through the chromatic spectrum. Of course the graph as it is has no information of direction. You might want to include for example that clockwise direction is the small interval and counterclockwise direction is the big counterinterval.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I did include the counterclockwise information, but later found this already developed system, looks interesting: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFKcevgRavAcrEcYSYv7Y-BEY5pyOH_Rf